# Foundation Library Causing Leak in application

Tags: iphone

[image][image]

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
    NSString *currentCountry=[carrier isoCountryCode];
    [networkInfo release];
```

I am using this piece of code in my application to determine the  country of user.I am getting leaks because of this and instruments shows the responsible library as foundation.I am using IOS 4.1 for testing.How can this be fixed.

Comment: You will likely have to file a bug with Apple.  The only thing you can really do is cache the answer, so you only leak once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is leaking?  Where is it retained/released?

Keep in mind that when Instruments identifies a leak, it is showing you *where the leak was allocated* and not the location where it might be over-retained.  There certainly are leaks in the system frameworks, but they are few and far enough between that it is safe to assume it is caused by your code until proven otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have posted the screen shot from instruments.

Comment: What is the backtrace of the highlighted retain?  And what is the back trace of the allocation in the first place?

Comment: I have posted the backtrace.Will this help.

Comment: Sure does;  as amattn said, file a bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com.  If you only see one of these things, don't worry about it.  If you see many, that is definitely an issue.  There doesn't look to be anything in that evidence that points to your code.   Congratulations! You are one of the lucky finders of one of the rare framework leaks, it seems! (Maybe -- this still could be something else).